# Already included file name 'c:/Users/prasad Shinde/Desktop/basic-app/src/Header.js'

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVFA5.png)

Already included file name 'c:/Users/prasad Shinde/Desktop/basic-app/src/Header.js' differs from file name 'c:/Users/prasad Shinde/Desktop/basic-app/src/header.js' only in casing. The file is in the program because: Imported via './Header' from file 'c:/Users/prasad Shinde/Desktop/basic-app/src/App.js' Root file specified for compilation

Already included file name 'c:/Users/prasad Shinde/Desktop/basic-app/src/Header.js' differs from file name 'c:/Users/prasad Shinde/Desktop/basic-app/src/header.js' only in casing. The file is in the program because: Imported via './Header' from file 'c:/Users/prasad Shinde/Desktop/basic-app/src/App.js' Root file specified for compilation